# Add values to datagridview from datatable

Tags: wpf, datagridview

i have datatable "dt" in which 2nd column has names and i inserted its values into datagridview "dgvbat".. Now i want to insert values into 4th column of "dgvbat" by using another datatable "dt1".
when i tried to insert values at 5th column previous 2nd column values are getting deleted..

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("SLNO", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Batsman", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Dismissal", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Bowler", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Runs", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Balls", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Mins", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Fours", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Sixes", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("SR", Type.GetType("System.String"));


        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= (team1.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            if (captain1 == keeper1)
            {
                if (team1[i] == captain1)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr.BeginEdit();
                    dr["SLNO"] = count;
                    count++;
                    dr["Batsman"] = team1[i];

                    dr.EndEdit();
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    dt.AcceptChanges();

                }
                else
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr.BeginEdit();
                    dr["SLNO"] = count;
                    count++;
                    dr["Batsman"] = team1[i];


                    dr.EndEdit();
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    dt.AcceptChanges();
                }

            }
```

here is my code to insert into 5th column

```
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("SLNO", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Batsman", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Dismissal", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Bowler", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Runs", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Balls", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Mins", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Fours", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt1.Columns.Add("Sixes", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt1.Columns.Add("SR", Type.GetType("System.String"));


            for (int m = 0; m <= (teamA.Count - 1); m++)
            {

                if (!DBNull.Value.Equals((dgvbat.Items[m] as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray[1]) && ((dgvbat.Items[m] as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray[1]).ToString() != "")
                {
                    if(cbxbatsmen.SelectedValue.ToString() == ((dgvbat.Items[m] as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray[1]))
                    {
                        Runs1 = Runs1 + i;
                        DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
                        dr.BeginEdit();

                        dr["Runs"] = Runs1;

                        dr.EndEdit();
                        dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
                        dt1.AcceptChanges();
                    }

                }
            }
            dgvbat.DataContext = dt1;
```

Thank U....

Comment: Try to keep your examples [clear and minimal](/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry for troubling u.. I wil try to keep clear and minimal...

Comment: Great! :-) Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can also take the site [tour]!